What is the best known bound for $|\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|$?
In this article, it is shown that $|\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|\leq 66.7 t^{\frac{27}{164}}$ for $t\geq 3$. What are the known results about the bounds (possibly best) of $|\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|$ for all values of $t$?

Since $\left| {\zeta \left( {\frac{1}{2} + {\rm i}t} \right)} \right| \le \left| {\zeta \left( {\frac{1}{2}} \right)} \right| < 1.461$ for $0\le t\le 3$, and $\left| {\zeta \left( {\frac{1}{2} + {\rm i}t} \right)} \right| = \left| {\zeta \left( {\frac{1}{2} - {\rm i}t} \right)} \right|$, $
\left| {\zeta \left( {\frac{1}{2} + {\rm i}t} \right)} \right| \le 66.7\left| t \right|^{27/164}  + 1.461$ is valid for all real $t$.

Bourgain proved that there exists an absolute constant $C > 0$ such that $|\zeta(1/2 + it)| \leq C(1 + |t|)^{13/84}$. One could make the constant $C$ explicit, though in practice this is not of much interest to most analytic number theorists.
